# Do rebound allocators have the same size_type and difference_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

After reading a very in-depth article on fancy pointers, where it is also described their correlation with allocators, I had a doubt. The paper covers several aspects of fancy pointers, but does not specify whether two different specializations of a `FancyPtr` type require to have the same `difference_type`.

By extension, I have the following question: given an allocator `A` and two different specializations, `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<T>` and `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<U>`, are `size_type` and `difference_type` guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: *a very in-depth article on fancy pointers* - could you please give a link to that article?

Comment: @Evg, it is a proposal, [Towards meaningful fancy pointers](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0773r0.html). However, it is used by some blogs as a reference to provide more insight into fancy pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ Standard Library provides the concept of allocators for memory management. The `rebind` mechanism is used to convert an allocator for one type to an allocator for another type, ensuring that the allocator's `typedef` members like `size_type` and `difference_type` are adapted to the new type.

In most cases, when you use `rebind` to adapt an allocator to a different type, the `size_type` and `difference_type` of the rebound allocator will remain the same as the original allocator. This is because these typedefs are often dependent on the allocator itself, rather than the types it allocates.

However, the C++ standard doesn't mandate that `size_type` and `difference_type` must be the same across all allocator specializations, even after rebinding. It's not guaranteed behavior. While it's common for `size_type` and `difference_type` to remain the same after rebinding, there might be specific scenarios or custom allocators where these types could differ.

If you want to ensure the behavior for a specific allocator or fancy pointer, you should refer to the documentation for that particular allocator or pointer type. Always rely on the documentation and specifications provided by the library or framework you are using, as there could be implementation-specific differences or variations.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't see any such requirement in the standard.